# how to stub a method that return a set rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, set, minitest, stub

**I need to stub a method async_actions_set that returns a set. How can I do it?**
I tried multiple ways like

```
class_name.any_instance.stubs(:async_actions_set?).returns([1, 2].to_set)
```

In my model, this is the condition I need to stub for

```
act_hash[:name].in?(async_actions_set)
```

But it is failing. Please help
async_actions_set returns a set

Comment: You said that you need to stub `async_actions_set` but you are stubbing `:method_name?`. Does this work `class_name.any_instance.stubs(:async_actions_set).returns([1, 2].to_set)`?

Comment: @Yakov no this is not working. I forgot to replace method_name with async_actions_set in question. apologies

Comment: Why you are putting a question mark to the end of the method `.stubs(:async_actions_set?)`?

Comment: What version of RSpec do you use?